# Scout eclipse execStore not markSaved

Tags: forms, save, eclipse-scout

I Would like to know how to set inside `execStore` function that "dirty" flag is still on.

I see that in scout function for saving `markSaved()` is called after `execStore()`. But what if I have some logic in `execStore()`, that can prevent save. In this case I would like not to be marked as saved.

Is there a way to avoid setting form as markSaved() ?
Is there aright scout way for handling this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can:

- throw an exception (`ProcessingException` or `VetoException`) during `execStore()`
- call `setFormStored(false);` [it works with Eclipse Mars]

See also in the Scout Forum: [execStore() and Confirmation](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/805383/)

PS: I did not test it with Eclipse Neon. Please report if this behavour has changed with Neon. I am interested in your findings.

Comment: I thing you are right and it should be done in execValidate()